# Android Kotlin Progress Bar become unresolved reference

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-progressbar

I am new at using Kotlin in Android Studio and I tried to learn on how to use the progress bar by following a simple tutorial on youtube. However, for some reason the "progressBar" on progressBar.max in MainActivity.kt is defined as unresolved reference although my code is identical with the guy in the video.

[This is activity_main.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kXJGE.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="335dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleY="10" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

[This is MainActivity.kt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrMNH.png)

```
package com.example.game1

import android.animation.ObjectAnimator
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

       progressBar.max=10

        val currentProgress = 6

        ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, propertyName: "progress", currentProgress)
        .setDuration(2000)
            .start()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you've watched a tutorial where somebody used Kotlin synthetics to access Views from the code. They are deprecated now and I suggest you use either Muhammad Ahmed solution or [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding)

In module's build.gradle locate this piece of code:

```
android {
    compileSdk 31
    ...
}
```

Now add the view binding build feature, it should look like this:

```
android {
    compileSdk 31

    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
   
   ...

}
```

After you make the changes, a blue bar at the top should appear. Sync your project and now it supports view binding.

Your MainActivity.kt should look like this:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding  // name of your layout in camelcase

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.progressBar.max = 10
    }
}
```

How do you access Views with the view binding? Use camelcase. For example, if you have TextView with id "tv_list_description" it can be accessed in the code like this:

`binding.tvListDescription.text = "Sample text"`

Answer (score 0):

You should get the instance of `ProgressBar` from xml i.e

```
findViewById(R.id.progressBar)
```

complete code

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var progressBar : ProgressBar
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar)
       progressBar.max=10

        val currentProgress = 6

        ObjectAnimator.ofInt(progressBar, propertyName: "progress", currentProgress)
        .setDuration(2000)
            .start()
    }
}
```

You can use view binding as well to get rid of findViewById